# Как получить подпись музыки имея ссылку?

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

Я хочу с помощью питон телебот телеграм бота получить всю музыку с тегом #jp из определенного канала (например t.me/audio2d)

Другими словами я хочу получить подпись музыки имея ссылку

Пока что я смог отправить только всю музыку с помощью ссылок но мне нужны только с подписем #jp

```
for i in range(...):
    bot.send_audio(message.chat.id, f'https://t.me/audio2d/{i}')
```

Comment: уточните, пожалуйста: с подписем == tag? нужно выкачать файлы из сообщений, которые имеют определенный тэг?

Comment: Я просто хочу узнать как можно получить тег (подпись) музыки имея ссылку (t.me/channel/123)